# UILabel Emoji SizeToFit works wrong

Tags: fonts, size, label, emoji

I am working with UILabel with Emoji and want to do SizeToFit. However, it return me wrong height of the label. Without Emoji it works great, what could be a problem and how to solve it?

```
UILabel * textLabel = [UILabel new];
    [textLabel setText:commentString];
    [textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
    [textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                   0,
                                   250,
                                   0)];
    [textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [textLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?